# Your database files were created by PostgreSQL version 13

Tags: opensuse, postgresql, suse, database

OS is openSUSE Tumbleweed. Previously I had PostgreSQL 13 installed. I just removed it by:

```
> sudo zypper rm 'postgres*'

> sudo zypper rr PostgreSQL

> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Then I install PostgreSQL 12 by instructions [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:PostgreSQL):

```
> sudo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:database:postgresql/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/ PostgreSQL

> sudo zypper ref

> sudo zypper in -f postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-contrib

> sudo zypper in -f postgresql-plperl postgresql-plpython postgresql-pltlc

> sudo systemctl enable postgresql

> sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

But the database status is faulty:

```
> sudo systemctl status postgresql.service  
[sudo] password for root:  
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-05-27 23:08:43 EDT; 2h 10min ago
    Process: 1576 ExecStart=/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql-script start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 21ms

May 27 23:08:43 localhost systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
May 27 23:08:43 localhost postgresql-script[1576]:  Your database files were created by PostgreSQL version 13.
May 27 23:08:43 localhost postgresql-script[1576]:  Could not find executables for this version.
May 27 23:08:43 localhost postgresql-script[1576]:  Please install the PostgreSQL server package for version 13.
May 27 23:08:43 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 23:08:43 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 27 23:08:43 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

For some reason, whatever I try, I cannot get rid of these status errors:

> Your database files were created by PostgreSQL version 13.
>
> Could not find executables for this version.
>
> Please install the PostgreSQL server package for version 13.

How can I install PostgreSQL 12 and get rid of PostgreSQL 13 database files?

Comment: While most things support upgrades, support for downgrades is far less common.  To downgrade from 13 to 12, your best bet is to reinstall pg 13, dump the database to text files, purge everything to do with pg 13 (including all db directories), install pg 12 and then import the database from the text backup.    But the real question is "Why would you do that?"  That's a good question at any time, but the first PG 14 beta was just announced a few days ago, and the final release of 14 should be out by then end of the year.   Is there some bug or problem in Pg 13 that prevents you from using it?

Comment: @cas I'm installing a platform that recommends Pg 12, so I decided to downgrade from 13 to 12! My plan is to reinstall Pg 13 and stick with it. I won't come back to 12 unless something goes wrong with 13. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @cas comment:

I decided to abandon the idea of downgrading from 13 to 12. I reinstalled Pg 13 and am sticking with it.

I work with a platform that recommends Pg 12. However, I won't come back to 12 unless something goes wrong with 13.